# When i want to navigate one activity page to another page my app is crashed in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

This is my MainActivity file

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.abvica.ui.login.LoginActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login2.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Button1.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this,login::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
      }
    }
}
```

this is AndroidManifest File

```
   <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name=".login"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".Verify_otp" />
     <activity
        android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
   </application>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="369dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
    android:text=" Welcome To App"
    android:textColor="#3888f1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.297"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="369dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
    android:text="Oyyaah! Your account has been varified.
                  Please update your details and password"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.111" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/welcome"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="369dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
    android:text="Enter Name"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.813" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.813"
    android:ems="10"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
    android:inputType="textPersonName|text"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:hint="@string/type_your_name"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="#3888f1"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Get Started"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

This is my code for button please help am new in android. This is my files and their code please tell me where I am going wrong. This is my main activity. I want to connect .login activity with main page please help

Comment: kindly share logcat please

Comment: Probably forgot to add the new Activity into the manifest

Comment: check two things 1) `Button1` nullability 2) make sure you have added both the activity to Manifest file out of one should have `<intent-filter><action and <category`as launcher

Comment: Please add the content of `activity_main.xml` to your question. Edit the question and copy the layout file in there.

Comment: Please also add the crash (exception) with stack trace from the logcat. This will help pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't initialized the button.
Initialize the button with `findViewById(R.id.buttonId);`

Comment: But after searching lot's of tutorials i didn't found to initialized this anywhere in kotlin

Comment: val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button) 
        button?.setOnClickListener() 
        { 
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, 
                R.string.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }

Comment: In Kotlin it is not necessary to use `findViewById()`. You can refer to the `View` directly by it's ID. I'm guessing that you aren't doing this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you a tring to call the wrong activity.

You have declared 2 other activities in Manifest, this:

```
<activity android:name=".login"></activity>
```

and this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
```

The button listener calls this intent:

```
val intent = Intent(this,login::class.java)
```

Maybe you implemented `.ui.login.LoginActivity` and is tring to call the wrong one `(.login)`
Try this insted:

```
val intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
```